# "require is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic2

I just started a [new project](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/) with ionic v2 and added [feedparser](https://github.com/danmactough/node-feedparser) to my project.

By using

```
ionic serve
```

I get a blank screen and the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>   This is the code that is used to load the dependencies:

```
declare var require: any;
var Feedparser = require('feedparser');
var request = require('request');
```

The first point is this part:

```
declare var require: any;
```

It has been mentioned in another thread, so I just put it there.

So I did some research and checked whether I have requirejs and stuff like that, but it didn't solved my problem.

After some time, I create another ionic project with an older version and it was no problem to include the feedparser examples - even with `declare var require:any;` thing.
So probably something has been changed with the release of ionic v2 and I really would like to modules like in the RC-Version.

Thank you.

EDIT:
Imports like

```
import * as Feedparser from 'feedparser';
```

are also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to install these node dependencies in your machine.

Use the below commands to have them installed in your project,

For RequireJS,

```
npm install --save requirejs
```

For FeedParser,

```
npm install --save feedparser
```

If you want them to install the above packages globally use `-g` instead of `--save` switch.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think this makes any sense, as I just need those dependencies in this project --> https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

Comment: In that case, like I commented in my post, you can use the `--save` option instead of `-g` while issuing the `npm install` command. I have updated my post.

Comment: Can you please update your post with your code?. I would like to see how you are importing the libraries

Comment: What happens when you change your statements from `require('feedparser');` `require('request');` to `require('./feedparser');` `require('./request');`

Comment: It is the same error as mentioned about. The require-statement itself seems to be the problem as it seems to be not available.